# Is there a better way to say " turn forwards"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is there a better way to say " turn forwards" when a student who is constantly facing backwards in the classroom?

Comment: You can use the same verb 'face' that you already used. "Face me", or "Face the front." Or "Sit still!"

Comment: If you say "turn around," then a clever troublemaker will turn 360 degrees.

Comment: What @WeatherVane says, plus *Face front* or *Face forward*.

Comment: Is this an English learning question? Or is it an English *teaching* question? Is the student a native speaker of English? Are you teaching English, or just teaching *in* English.  Is there a good reason not to address the student in their native language?

Comment: It is not a learning question nor a teaching one.  I'm sorry if I wasn´t enough clear. I want students o keep looking to the front and I dont know which is the best  command / instruction  to address to the specfic student.